# Kafka Consumer: polling from a assigned partition that was already paused by another consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's suppose Kafka Group Coordinator assigns a paused partition to a consumer. Will the consumer be able to poll messages from this partition that was already paused by another consumer in the same consumer group?

UPDATE: I add an example to clarify the scenario:
We have two consumer C1 and C2 in the same consumer group . They are  subscribed to the same topic T1 which has 2 partitions: P0 and P1. T1-P0 is assigned to C1 whereas T1-P1 is assigned to C2. Suddenly, C1 pauses T1-P0 (it calls C1.pause(T1-P0)) and after a while C1 crashes or is closed. A rebalance take place and now T1-P0 is assigned to C2. C2 receives a topic partition had being set in pause. Does T1-P0 remain pause status for C2? Will C2 be able to fetch messages from T1-P0 ?

Answer (score 0):

A partition of a topic will be assigned to one and only consumer from a consumer group. I'm not sure what you meant by paused in this context. But if a consumer is timed out, or is no longer reachable, a rebalance would happen, and the partition allocated to the said consumer would get assigned to another consumer from the same group.

If you meant pausing consumption programmatically using [this](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause(java.util.Collection)) api, then the api document is very clear -

"Suspend fetching from the requested partitions. Future calls to poll(long) will not return any records from these partitions until they have been resumed using resume(Collection). Note that this method does not affect partition subscription. In particular, **it does not cause a group rebalance when automatic assignment is used**."

In that case, to resume the consumption, you have to programmatically [resume](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#resume(java.util.Collection)).

Comment: Let me explain the scenario with an example: We have two consumer C1 and C2 in the same consumer group . They are  subscribed to the same topic T1 which has 2 partitions: P0 and P1. T1-P0 is assigned to C1 whereas T1-P1 is assigned to C2. Suddenly, C1 pauses T1-P0 (it calls C1.pause(T1-P0)) and after a while C1 crashes or is closed. A rebalance take place and now T1-P0 is assigned to C2. C2 receives a topic partition had being set in pause. Does T1-P0 remain pause status for C2? Will C2 be able to fetch messages from T1-P0 ?